# Mark-down tables fail to display on the English Language Learners Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, markdown

I was trying to answer a question on [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/).

I tried to draw a table:

```
| A header | Another header |
| -------- | -------------- |
| First    | row            |
| Second   | row            |
```

There is a previewer which displays what one's answer will look like before clicking the <kbd>Post Your Answer</kbd> button.

The previewer does not display a table, instead we have:

[image: table shown as single line in preview]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

^That's a table at the top of the edit window^

This is a table with no blank line of text before it:
| A header | Another header |
| -------- | -------------- |
| First    | row            |
| Second   | row            |

This is a table with a blank line of text before it:

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

All of these look like words with no formatting in the preview window:
[image]

So, it seems ell.meta.stackexchange.com has different problems with previewing table formatting than meta.stackexchange.com does, and the same problems with displaying tables once it's submitted.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see at [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=table%20preview) there have been quite a few reported bugs with table preview, Known issues: if the table contains any tab characters it will render incorrectly. There must be a blank line before and after any table.

Comment: Specifically, it seems to be that the [markdown preview isn't working](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382240/323179)